# Postgres DATE_TRUNC is shifting timestamp

Tags: python, postgresql, postgresql-11

I'm using a python package called architect that helps in using Postgres partition in Django model. And I have set up  partition table for every month. But in the check constraints, I see that the truncated date is being shifted. For example

`DATE_TRUNC('month','2020-09-12 15:23:00+05:45')` gives `2020-09-01 05:45:00+05:45`

Due to this, the check constraints becomes

```
CONSTRAINT "transactionservice_transaction_y2020m09_TransactionDate_check" CHECK ("TransactionDate" >= '2020-09-01 05:45:00+05:45'::timestamp with time zone AND "TransactionDate" < '2020-10-01 05:45:00+05:45'::timestamp with time zone)
)
```

This results in the transaction from `2020-9-1 02:03:33` being inside the transaction table of `2020-08` Which is not what I want.

I tried this from pgadmin and the output is `2020-09-01 00:00:00+05:45` which is what I except.

But the sql code executed from the architect package results in the above shift.

Here is the part of the code from architect which adds the check contraint.

```
def _get_date_definitions(self):
    """
    Returns definitions for date partition subtype.
    """
    patterns = {
        'day': '"y"YYYY"d"DDD',
        'week': '"y"IYYY"w"IW',
        'month': '"y"YYYY"m"MM',
        'year': '"y"YYYY',
    }
    try:
        pattern = patterns[self.constraint]
    except KeyError:
        raise PartitionConstraintError(
            model=self.model.__name__,
            dialect=self.dialect,
            current=self.constraint,
            allowed=patterns.keys())
    return {
        'formatters': {'pattern': pattern},
        'variables': [
            "match := DATE_TRUNC('{constraint}', NEW.{{column}});",
            "tablename := '{{parent_table}}_' || TO_CHAR(NEW.{{column}}, '{pattern}');",
            "checks := '{{column}} >= ''' || match || ''' AND {{column}} < ''' || (match + INTERVAL '1 {constraint}') || '''';"
        ]
    }
```

Can anyone explain to me what's causing the shift

Comment: What type is the column? `timestamp` or `timestamptz`?

Comment: its  timestamptz

Answer (score 0):

Observe that `2020-09-01 05:45:00+05:45` and `2020-09-01 00:00:00Z` are the same point in time in different time zones. One is in +05:45 and one is in UTC. Likely you application is interpreting `2020-09-01 00:00:00` as UTC and then changing it to the application's time zone.

If the column is a `timestamp` with no time zone, `date_trunc` will produce a timestamp with no zone. My time zone is -0700.

```
select date_trunc('month', timestamp '2020-09-12 15:23:00+05:45')
2020-09-01 00:00:00

select date_trunc('month', timestamptz '2020-09-12 15:23:00+05:45')
2020-09-01 00:00:00-07
```

`2020-09-01 00:00:00` is an ambiguous point in time. Your application might interpret it as UTC or in your application's time zone +05:45. It seems to be interpreting it as UTC and then translating it to your application's time.`2020-09-01 00:00:00` in UTC is  `2020-09-01 05:45:00+05:45`.

The [Django documentation on time zones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/) seems to confirm this.

> When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.

I'm not familiar with Django to say exactly how to solve this. In the [Troubleshooting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#troubleshooting) section there is "3. now.date() is yesterday! (or tomorrow)" about the pitfalls of converting a datetime to a date which may be relevant.

Comment: so, when I insert a row with a timestamp of UTC, the date_trunc truncates it into 2020-09-01 00:00:00 in UTC, and Postgres show me that timestamp in my timezone?
Now if I insert a row with timestamp that's in  my timezone then  date_trunc should work as expected right?

Comment: @jimmy The fundamental issue is that a timestamp/datetime is an absolute point in time, but the date is not. `2020-09-01 00:00:00+05:45` and `2020-08-31 18:15:00Z` are the same point in time, but one is the beginning of Sept, the other is the end of August. If you want the beginning of the month in your time zone, and you're doing this with timestamps, you have to be careful to convey it with the time zone still attached. As either `2020-09-01 00:00:00+05:45` or `2020-08-31 18:15:00Z`. Never as `2020-09-01 00:00:00` which is ambiguous. That's my educated guess.

Comment: I want 2020-09-01 00:00:00+05:45 to be the output of date_trunc. And the current output 2020-09-01 05:45:00+05:45 will totally mess up the partition my putting rows of september into the rows of august. I tried both UTC and my Timezone(Asia/Kathmandu) but still i alway get the shifted timestamp.

Comment: @jimmy Reading a little about architect, I believe its `date_trunc` will be operating in the database's time zone. Since this is table partitioning, does it matter exactly which partition a row winds up in? It should have no effect if you're querying the master table. You also may wish to use simpler [native partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) and a tool such as [pg_partman](https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman) to manage them.